# XFCE make media keys work globally?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I'm running Gentoo with xfce.  I also have a logitech keyboard that has media keys like play and pause.  The keys work fin in most programs, like vlc, if the program  has the focus.  I want these keys to work globally whether the program has the focus or not so that if I press pause on the keyboard it will pause no matter if the program has the focus or not.  Is there a setting or utility that can make this happen?

I have found ways to bind the keys to specific programs, but I want it to work no matter what media program I am using, since I use a few.